# Javascript weird object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got this code from a javascript file that looks like some object but Im not sure.
How can I use this data?

```
DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 36 }, 
[
 [36,13,'Arsenal',1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
,[36,24,'Aston Villa',2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
,[36,184,'Burnley',3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
]);
```

Comment: That's just JSON syntax.

Comment: What this is used for will depend on how the library where this code is interprets this, may be a method invocation also.

Comment: I'm new into the JSON and javascript, can you tell me some simple code how to use the data?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Javascript file where this is used ?

Comment: @sebcap26 That is definitely *not* JSON. In JSON you can't use single quotes, every property must be surrounded by double quotes and you can't have trailing commas in objects and array.

Comment: here is the script
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13089074/script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataStore //some class
.prime //probably the function
(
'standings', //argument 1 which is a string calling a string event
{ stageId: 36 }, //argument 2 an object, must be referencing to a stage event

[
 [36,13,'Arsenal',1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
,[36,24,'Aston Villa',2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
,[36,184,'Burnley',3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,]
] //Argument 3 Multidimensional Array which looks like some stats for a certain team

);
```

Is this some highscore table for a game?

Answer (score 1):

What you see here is an array (not an object), which elements are 3 other arrays, which elements are numbers and Strings.

Here it is in a more conventional form :

```
var myArray = [
  [36, 13, 'Arsenal', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , , ],
  [36, 24, 'Aston Villa', 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , , ],
  [36, 184, 'Burnley', 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , , ]
];

myArray[0][1]; // 13
myArray[1][2]; // 'Aston Villa'
myArray[2][31]; // undefined
```

From the script I reckon this is data about some football clubs.